In macro #define can we use #pragma push_macro and pop_macro
My goal is to remove name from SECTION_STOP in the following macros:
// Start creates the object
#define SECTION_START(name, ...) \
  auto section_##name = create_section_name(#name, ## __VA_ARGS__);

// Stop destroys the object
#define SECTION_STOP(name) \
  section_##name.reset();

I see that C++ macros support both the COUNTER operator and a concept of pushing and popping macro names.
I have a rough idea:
// Start creates the object
#define SECTION_START(name, ...) \
  #define CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER __COUNTER__ \
  auto section_##CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER = create_section_name(#name, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
  _Pragma("push_macro(\"CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER\")") \
  #undef CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER

// Stop destroys the object
#define SECTION_STOP() \
  _Pragma("pop_macro(\"CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER\")") \
  section_##CURRENT_SECTION_COUNTER.reset();

The above wouldn't work because there are a number of issues with it (can't have nested #define and need some sort of stringify operator). But is it possible to leverage __COUNTER__ (or something similar) alongside #pragma push_macro/pop_macro to achieve what I am after?

C macros do not support either counting or push / pop, in the sense that these features are not part of standard C.  Some C implementations support one or the other or both, but that's different, especially if you're not using such an implementation.

In any case, I'm not aware of even any common extension that provides a means for one macro to define another macro.  That seems to be the main hurdle you would need to overcome, at least for the kind of approach to the problem that you are contemplating.

Have you considered looking for an alternative approach that doesn't rely on macros in the first place?

@JohnBollinger That is a very good point. I mixed things up as I am using macros to solve solutions in both C and C++. This specific question would be specific to some C++ implementations.

@JohnBollinger to answer your question about utilizing an approach that doesn't rely on macros, I was thinking about simply attempting straight API calls instead, but the macro approach is important as I am also implementing a static bool into the macro implementation to know if it is the first time START is called

Preprocessor macros (in C or C++) are forbidden by the standard from expanding to a preprocessor directive (roughly speaking, anything consisting of a # followed by a keyword).  This disallows a macro expanding to a #pragma directive just as much as it disallows creating a macro that #defines another macro.   This will (generally speaking) be the reason the macros you have are defined as they are - the alternative you want is not valid in standard C or standard C++.

@Peter, the question of a macro expanding to a #pragma directive is moot.  Working around that is the express purpose of the _Pragma operator, which the OP shows they already know about.
